# Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException when trying to read text file using java.util.Scanner + write file into different matrix

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to java and i write this code to sum up two matrix.
both matrix are filled by reading from input.in file. 
i have two question about this code:
1. in executing I confront this error :
i don't know what cause this error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at s.s.main(s.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)`

my code is:

```
package example; 

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner; 


public class aaaa {
public static void main (String [] args)  throws FileNotFoundException{
int [][] matrix1 = new int[4][4];
int [][] matrix2 = new int[4][4];
int [][] matrix3 = new int[4][4];
String file = "c:\\input.txt";



    Scanner text = new Scanner(new File(file));

    while (text.next()!=null){
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
                matrix1[i][j]= text.nextInt();
    }


    while (text.next()!=null){
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
                matrix2[i][j]= text.nextInt();
        }

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
         System.out.println(matrix3[i][j] + matrix3[i][j]);}}
```

what's wrong with this code?

new code after replacing  Pablo Francisco Pérez suggestion :

```
public class aaaa {

public static void main (String [] args)  throws FileNotFoundException{
    int [][] matrix1 = new int[4][4];
    int [][] matrix2 = new int[4][4];
    int [][] matrix3 = new int[4][4];
    String file = "c:\\input.txt";



    Scanner text = new Scanner(new File(file));

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(!text.hasNextInt()) break;
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(!text.hasNextInt()) break;
            matrix1[i][j]= text.nextInt();
        }
    }


    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(!text.hasNextInt()) break;
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(!text.hasNextInt()) break;
            matrix2[i][j]= text.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
            System.out.println(matrix3[i][j] + matrix3[i][j]);}}
```

2.while I am trying to read from input.in and write it to different matrix but after executing this code content of two matrixes is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown by a `Scanner` object in the execution of `next` and thus it seems to me that `text` has exhausted its input source.

You should control that you have more elements at `text` before asking it for more integers as you tried but not at the outer loop as you do but at the deepest level.

Right now you are loading bunches of 4x4=16 elements if you can get an element before starting your loop.

Try with:

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    if(!text.hasNextInt()) break;
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        if(!text.hasNextInt()) break;
        matrix1[i][j]= text.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3496654 Can you edit your question to include your new code?

Comment: @user3496654 I think this second message is from another source code, `s.s.main` is not the main method you posted.

Comment: @user3496654 Did I solve your problem? In that case you can accept my answer. Don't do it if you doesn't consider I solved your problem our that my answer is poor.

Comment: i have another problem with this code. can i ask it here or i should open other topic?

Comment: @user3496654 It depends, if it is related to the code you posted you can edit your question. Otherwise, you can ask a different question.

Comment: @user3496654 Concerning your question second part, did you check the input file have different values? How big is your input file?

Comment: OK there was a problem from my file.